# Function printing twice when i call it

Tags: python, function

im trying to refresh the HUD of my game by calling the function hud() everytime that a data changes, but it shows twice the information:

```
def hud(nickname):
    os.system('cls')

    global rodada
    rodada += 1

    print(f'\033[33mRodada\033[m: {rodada}')

    print(f'\033[92m{nickname}\033[m: {pontos_jogador_total} | \033[92mComputador\033[m: {pontos_computador_total}')

    # Opção de ajuda com manilhas
    if modo_ajuda_manilhas == False:
        print(f'\033[91mVira\033[m: {vira[0]}')
    else:
        for i in baralho_check:
            if vira[0] in i:
                print(f'\033[91mVira\033[m: {vira[0]} | \033[91mTodas manilhas\033[m: ', end='')
                for i in baralho_check[baralho_check.index(i)]:
                    print(f'{i}', end=' ')

    if ver_cartas_adversario:
        print("\n\033[33mMão computador:\033[m")
        for i in cartas_mao_computador:
            print(f'| {i}', end=' | ')

    # Mostrar as cartas na mesa
    if len(cartas_na_mesa) == 0:
        print(f'\n\n\033[91mMesa\033[m:\n|   | |   |')
    else:
        print(f'\n\n\033[91mMesa\033[m:')
        for i in cartas_na_mesa:
            print(f'| {i}', end=' | ')

    # Mostrar mão Jogador
    print(f'\n\033[92mSua mão\033[m:')
    for i in cartas_mao_jogador:
        print(f'| {i}', end=' | ')

começar_novo_jogo() -> starts a new game function
distribuir_cartas() -> give the cards to the players function
hud(nickname) -> HUD funcion and the parameter nickname given to it
jogador_joga(1) -> trowing my first card in my hand to the table (mesa)
hud(nickname) ->  refreshing the HUD to show 1 less card in my hand (mão) and 1 more card in the table (mesa)
```

output:

```
| 4 ♦ | | 4 ♠ | | 5 ♥ | Rodada: 2
Gustavo: 0 | Computador: 0
Vira: 2 ♥


Mesa:
| 4 ♦ |
Sua mão:
| 4 ♠ | | 5 ♥ |
```

my problem:

```
| 4 ♦ | | 4 ♠ | | 5 ♥ | Rodada: 2 <--- here, i just want to show the "Rodada: 2" and not my "cards" at the top of my HUD
```

i think the problem is that im calling the function HUD twice, but how can i refesh the HUD whitout showing my cards at the top?

images that can help:
[Code printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5e5F.png)

[Output printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0dTo.png)

Comment: obs: The cards that is showing at the top is the same cards of the past round (before the refreshing)

Comment: are the cards at before `Rodada:` part of something else (has the function already run a second time?) When is this occurring in you code? because it could either be (without additional information) a new line error when you change the print statements with end, or it could be a different function that is printing out the cards and you aren't clearing the output?